# Adobe Flex Inactive Component

Tags: apache-flex

I have a question about Flex.

I want to add a check box so that when user clicks it, some fields in the form (`NumericStepper`, `TextInput` and `CustomDataField`) will be deactivated. My check box id is `'check'` and it has a click method.

When user click the checkbox the fields will be inactivated. Then if user uncheck the checkbox, the fields above will become active again.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an EventListener to the checkbox like this:

```
myCheckbox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

private function changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    if(myCheckbox.selected == true)
    {
        otherComponent.enabled = false;
    } else {
        otherComponent.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

You need the Event.CHANGE to know when checkboxes are toggled on or off, the CLICK event doesn't work in this particular case.